# Select children with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, image, select, jquery-selectors

I'm struggling to find an option to select the img of the div.

In my markup I only have this:

```
      <div class="slideshow-container">
                <div id="loading" class="loader"></div>
                <div id="slideshow" class="slideshow"></div>
            </div>
```

When it is rendered in browser it is like this:
[image: Inspect source]

This is the gallery I use: [Galleriffic](http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/index.html)

I want to select the images of the `#slideshow` and add class to it. Please help.

UPDATE:
In the gallery js file I have found where the image is added, but I cant get it to add a class.

Here's what I'm trying:
[image]

Comment: Found the answer here:
[Galleriffic support and issues.](https://code.google.com/p/galleriffic/issues/detail?id=47) Hope it helps, Good luck and thanks to all.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:- You may need to look at the jquery selectors.

```
 $('#slideshow img').addClass('newclass');
```

If you want to specifically look at the images inside your hyperlink and done want to affect any other images if present in the `#slideshow` directly you should use this.:-

```
 $("#slideshow > .advance-link > img").addClass('newClass');
```

Comment: Do you have it under `$(function(){...});`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('#slideshow').find('img').addClass('someclass');
```

Comment: I don't uderstand, but it's not working... I tryed to put it in the begining of all scripts, in the end of the page... No effect... Wtf?

Comment: Agm, no, but I added it and still nothing.
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#slideshow').find('img').addClass('someclass');
});

Comment: please create a fiddle describing the problem then.  Is it possible that you have an iframe? if so then knowing more about that iframe would help.   

or maybe that $ is not jQuery?  if so then use `jQuery('#slideshow').find('img')`

Comment: to use `function($)` like this you'll want to use `(function($) { $('#slideshow').find('img').addClass('someclass'); })(jQuery)`

perhaps you have `$` reserved globally by another library like prototype?  You could use `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();` and then use `$j` as you see `$` used in other jQuery posts/ docs e.g. `$j('#slideshow').find('img').addClass('someclass');`

Answer (score 1):

I accomplished this by modifying the refresh function of galleriffic:

```
refresh: function() {
   // skip to this line of code:
   if (!imageData.image) {
      var image = new Image();

      // Add this line
      image.className = your_class_name_here
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $("#slideshow").find('.advance-link').children('img').addClass('newClass');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#slideshow').find('img').addClass('classname')
```